# There are several blending modes in Adobe Pr. Is there a way to "ease into" a mode without having it abruptly change?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I have a clip of around 10 seconds. I want the first half to be in normal blend mode, but the second half to be in "Lighter Color" blend mode. (I am inserting that clip inside another clip and want it to blend with it in a non obstructive way in case you need to know why I'm asking).

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to make it slowly change blend modes (like a fade) over the course of that 10 second clip. Is there a workaround for this?

If there is a solution with Ae as well I'd still like to know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can keyframe this.
I would duplicate my clip, and set one with the first blend mode, the other with the second.  Then crossfade between the two.